# Change filename of existing file on SharePoint Document library using REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a question on how to change an existing file on SharePoint document library using REST API. I have a couple of files in the location `http://site url/<RootFolder>/<SubFolder>/File.docx`. I have a UI where it lists all the files from this subfloder location. When the user clicks on edit i am enabling the file name as textbox where the user can change the name of the file.

After doing some research i found that Constructing an endpoint that looks like this: `https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(<item id>)` we can edit the file metadata properties. But i could not able to figure out the best way to update the filename of existing document that resides on SharePoint Doc library.

Could someone please help me with the REST API query to fetch the file and the approach to update the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the MoveTo Method to do this as described here in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileMoveTo.

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/filename.docx')
    /moveto(newurl='/Other Folder/filename.docx',flags=1)
    ?@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider at least two options:

### Option 1. Rename file name

You could update the name of the existing list item as demonstrated below

**Example**

```
function rename(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,fileName){
   var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId +  ")";
   return executeJson(endpointUrl)
   .then(function(data){                 
      var itemPayload = {};
      itemPayload['__metadata'] = {'type': data.d['__metadata']['type']};
      itemPayload['Title'] = fileName;
      itemPayload['FileLeafRef'] = fileName;
      var itemUrl = data.d['__metadata']['uri'];
      var headers = {};
      headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
      headers["If-Match"] =  "*";
      return executeJson(itemUrl,"POST",headers,itemPayload);
   });
}

var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; // web url
var listTitle = "Documents";  //list title
var itemId = 1;  //list item id
var fileName = "SP User Guide.docx"; //new file name

rename(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,fileName)
.done(function(item){
   console.log('Renamed');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

### Option 2. Move file via [MoveTo REST endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileMoveTo)

**Example**

```
function moveTo(webUrl,sourceFileUrl,targetFileUrl){
   var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + sourceFileUrl + "')/moveto(newurl='" + targetFileUrl + "',flags=1)";
   return executeJson(endpointUrl,"POST");
}

var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; // web url
var sourceFileUrl = "/Documents/SP2010.docx";
var targetFileUrl = "/Documents/SP2013.docx";

moveTo(webUrl,sourceFileUrl,targetFileUrl)
.done(function(item){
   console.log('Done');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

---

`executeJson` function:

```
function executeJson(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    headers = headers || {};
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

Comment: I am having a problem with approach number 2. I have a case where there's file abc.txt and I rename it to abc.txt.old, but if abc.txt.old is already present then instead of merging the versions of the file, this API call overwrites it (new version is 1.0) after the API call.
Is there a flag with which I can achieve a merge in the versions instead of hard replace?

Comment: Let's say if the existing abc.txt.old have Exposures etc, they also go away after the MoveTo finishes.

Comment: What's the solution to this {
  "error": {
    "code": "-2130575257, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "The specified name is already in use.\n\nThe document or folder name was not changed.  To change the name to a different value, close this dialog and edit the properties of the document or folder."
    }
  }
}
I'm using Option 1. Is there a way to merge the 2 files (the new one with the existing one)?